# Is it legal to use Apple-made ringtones in my own app?

Tags: xcode, swift, notifications, ringtone

I am creating an alarm app, and I wanted to know if it is legal to download Apple made ringtones from the internet and use them in my app for a local notification sound?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question was just within on-topic. I think the developer agreement and the app have controlling interest over the legal. If you don't get any answers, then maybe [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This seems to suggest no: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5868365?tstart=0